# Whitespace before %c specification in the format specifier of scanf function in C

Tags: c, character, scanf, format-specifiers

When I don't include white space between `%d` and `%c` specification in the format string of `scanf()` function in the following program, and give input during run-time as "4 h", then the output is "Integer = 4 and Character= .

How exactly variable `"c"` takes the input in this case and what difference does it make if i include a white space between `%d` and `%c` specification ?

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    printf("Enter an Integer and a character:\n");
    scanf("%d %c",&i,&c);
    printf("Integer = %d and Character = %c\n",i,c);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: @petercordes  I opened this, since I think this is another case, that I met again, namely putting `%c` without preceding space on a single line, there is no question about "newline in the buffer" so it is somewhat different.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I think I closed it as a duplicate of [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789) because the ultimate problem is the same: `%c` itself (unlike other conversions) will read a space if that's the next character.  But a literal space in the format string consumes an arbitrary amount of whitespace.  Reopening is fine, though; the answer here is good.

Answer (score 8):

If you read the specification for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) carefully, most format specifiers skip leading white space.  In Standard C, there are three that do not:

- `%n` — how many characters have been processed up to this point
- `%[…]` — scan sets
- `%c` — read a character.

(POSIX adds a fourth, `%C`, which is equivalent to `%lc`.)

> Input white-space characters (as specified by `isspace`) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifier.

Adding the space between `%d` and `%c` means that optional white space is skipped after the integer is read and before the (not white space) character is read.

Note that literal characters in a format string (other than white space — for example, the `X` and `Y` in `"X%dY"`) do not skip white space.  Matching such characters does not count as a successful conversion either; they do not affect the return value from `scanf()` et al.

Comment: Also, including/excluding the whitespace doesn't effect the program if two integers are in play instead of a character and an integer.
Why ??

Comment: @Shubhamdubey2111 The answer lies in "If you read the specification for scanf() carefully, most format specifiers **(like %d)** skip leading white space. In Standard C, there are three that do not:"

Answer (score 1):

A space before `%c` specifier in `scanf` instruct it to skip any number of white-spaces. In other words, read from standard input until and unless a non-white-space character or keyboard interrupt is found.

Comment: This means that when i don't use the whitespace between %d and %c specifications then while taking the input as "4 h",compiler assings the "whitespace" to the char variable 'c'
Am i correct ??

Comment: @Shubhamdubey2111; Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Also, including/excluding the whitespace doesn't effect the program if two integers are in play instead of a character and an integer. Why ??

Comment: That's work for `%c` specifier _only_? Certainly not consume leading white-space it applies to at least 2 other format specifiers.