# Searching a char value inside char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, search, input, char

I am studying the c language in our class I create some code to find a some number inside other array but when I try it with char value my code is not working in same as working with int value.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int  num, i, j;
    char a[99], ele;

    printf("Enter the Character element:");
    // get the length of array by the num value
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter the values: \n");
    // a loop for getting values for our a[array] line by line
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ ) {
        // get value by index i for array a index by index
        //printf("%d\t", (i+1));
        //if ( i + 1  == num ) {
        //    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
        //} else {
            scanf("%c", &a[i]);
        //}

    }

    printf("Enter the Character elements to be searched:");
    // get the value for ele, to use ele for searching inside our a[array]
    scanf("%c", &ele);

    // we need to set i to 0 for our while loop
    j = 0;
    // use the while loop to
    while ( j < num && ele != a[j]) {
        j++;
    }
    if ( j < num ) {
        printf("Character found at the location = %d\n\n\n", j + 1);
    } else {
        printf("Character Not Found!\n\n\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I try to fixed many time but each time I get error, so the above one is working but it scape the some input value during input.

Comment: Please add an example input where you're code doesn't do what you expect

Comment: if I add \n after %c in this line (scanf("%c", &a[i]);) the input will fixed but after inputing the last value the second scanf this one (scanf("%c", &ele);) dos not work and the program going to be end.

Comment: Think carefully about *every* key pressed on your keyboard when running this program. There's much more than just alpha-numeric characters going on here, starting with pressing Enter upon input of your number `num`. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504282/1322972).

Comment: please take some time to understand the `scanf()` behaviour

Comment: The takeaway here is that , for good reason, the `%c` directive differs from most other `scanf` directives in more than just the type expected for the corresponding variable.

Comment: "but each time I get error". Compile error? Runtime error? Explain this error please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig), [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) for your advices, the whitespace in  `scanf(" %c", &a[i]);` and `scanf(" %c", &ele);` make some unwanted inputs so this is a my code and its working like charm. :))

I just add space before the `%c` and every thing is okay.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int  num, i, j;
    char a[99], ele;

    printf("Enter the Character element:");
    // get the length of array by the num value
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter the values: \n");
    // a loop for getting values for our a[array] line by line
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ ) {
        // get value by index i for array a index by index
        printf("%d\t", (i+1));
        scanf(" %c", &a[i]);


    }

    printf("Enter the Character elements to be searched:");
    // get the value for ele, to use ele for searching inside our a[array]
    scanf(" %c", &ele);

    // we need to set i to 0 for our while loop
    j = 0;
    // use the while loop to
    while ( j < num && ele != a[j]) {
        j++;
    }
    if ( j < num ) {
        printf("Character found at the location = %d\n\n\n", j + 1);
    } else {
        printf("Character Not Found!\n\n\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your program that causes surprising behavior:

- `scanf("%d", &num)` reads a number from standard input but leaves the newline typed by the user pending as the next character to be read.
- Further calls to `scanf("%c", &a[i]);` read this pending newline and `num-1` more characters from the user, leaving the rest of his input pending...
- The final `scanf("%c", &ele);` reads whatever byte is pending in stdin, either a character from the user or the pending newline.

Hence the program behaves as if it does not execute the last `scanf()`.

You should read input from the user one line at a time with `fgets()` or flush the pending newline with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, i, c;
    char a[99], ele;

    printf("Enter the number of character:");
    // get the length of array by the num value
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 0 || num > 99)
        return 1;

    // consume the rest of the line typed by the user
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
        continue;

    printf("Enter the characters on a single line: \n");
    // a loop for getting values for our a[array]
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (scanf("%c", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    // consume the rest of the line typed by the user
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
        continue;

    printf("Enter the character to be searched: ");
    // get the value for ele, to use ele for searching inside our a[array]
    if (scanf("%c", &ele) != 1)
        return 1;

    // consume the rest of the line typed by the user
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
        continue;

    // use a for loop
    for (i = 0; i < num && ele != a[i]; i++) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i < num) {
        printf("Character %c found at the offset %d\n\n\n", ele, i);
    } else {
        printf("Character %c Not Found!\n\n\n", ele);
    }
    return 0;
}
```