# Incorrect Floating point Output in C Program

Tags: c

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   float percentage;
   int sp;
   int bp;

   percentage = (sp-bp)/bp*100;

   scanf("%d %d", &sp, &bp );
   printf("%.2f%%", percentage);

   return 0;
}
```

Sample input :

```
150 85
```

Sample output :

```
76.47%
```

but my output is :

```
-100.00%
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why is `percentage = (sp-bp)/bp*100;` above the `scanf` call that initializes the values? The program runs top to bottom, so this is doing arithmetic with a bunch of uninitialized variables.

Comment: @ggorlen  That is among the issues.  There's also the problem of performing arithmetic on integral types and expecting a result in a floating point type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why dividing two integers doesn't get a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221776/why-dividing-two-integers-doesnt-get-a-float)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really read the values **before** using them:

```
scanf("%d %d", &sp, &bp);
percentage = ...
```

Secondly, this:

```
percentage = (sp-bp)/bp*100;
```

Does an integer division, so the rest of the division is totally discarded and you will end up with:

```
(150 - 85) / 85 == 0
0 * 100 == 0.
```

You should cast one end of the division to `float` before doing the operation:

```
percentage = (sp-bp)/(float)bp * 100;
```

---

Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   float percentage;
   int sp;
   int bp;

   scanf("%d %d", &sp, &bp);

   percentage = (sp-bp)/(float)bp * 100;

   printf("%.2f%%", percentage);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Explanation will add soon.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

   float percentage=0;
   int sp=0;
   int bp=0;

   scanf("%d%d", &sp, &bp );
   //printf("\n%d%d", bp,sp);

   percentage = (sp-bp)/(float)bp*100;


   printf("%.2f%%", percentage);


}
```

***Edit***

*Explain what i changed*

As you scanning two integer with one `scanf()` function.
use `scanf("%d%d", &sp, &bp );`

Only remove space between two `%d %d`.
This white space is useless, because `scanf()` with %d format specifier consume any number of white space. but if you want to scan with `%c` use that.
`scanf()` consumes white space for all specifier except for `%c`, `%n`,  `%[…]`.

see more info on [Jonathan Leffler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504282/7508077)

Initialize all variables like this (Declare and Define)

```
float percentage=0;
int sp=0;
int bp=0;
```

Because when we declare a variable inside function this is not initiate and have garbage value. This may cause undefined behavior.see [C section](https://dev.to/idanarye/dont-initialize-your-variables-40d)

Suppose a situation that `scanf()` cant work properly and the integers `sp` and `bp` values remain with defaults. If we don't initiate them, garbage value remains.

Do declare and define at one time and initiate to zero. [see](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335875/325759)
[more on declare define](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/)

Add `(float)` explicit conversion to the division.

```
(sp-bp)/(float)bp*100;
```

In C result number of An integer that divides to another integer converted to integer and you lost decimal part because that is truncated.
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)