# What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have very frequently seen people discouraging others from using `scanf` and saying that there are better alternatives. However, all I end up seeing is either *"don't use `scanf`"* or *"here's a correct format string"*, and never any examples of the *"better alternatives"* mentioned.

For example, let's take this snippet of code:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

This reads the whitespace that was left in the input stream after the last conversion. The usual suggested solution to this is to use:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

or to not use `scanf`.

Since `scanf` is bad, what are some ANSI C options for converting input formats that `scanf` can usually handle (such as integers, floating-point numbers, and strings) without using `scanf`?

Answer (score 104):

The most common ways of reading input are:

- using `fgets` with a fixed size, which is what is usually suggested, and
- using `fgetc`, which may be useful if you're only reading a single `char`.

To convert the input, there are a variety of functions that you can use:

- `strtoll`, to convert a string into an integer
- `strtof`/`d`/`ld`, to convert a string into a floating-point number
- `sscanf`, which is not *as* bad as simply using `scanf`, although it does have most of the downfalls mentioned below
- There are no good ways to parse a delimiter-separated input in plain ANSI C. Either use `strtok_r` from POSIX or `strtok`, which is not thread-safe. You could also [roll your own](https://github.com/JL2210/minilibc/raw/master/src/string/strtok_r.c) thread-safe variant using `strcspn` and `strspn`, as `strtok_r` doesn't involve any special OS support.
- It may be overkill, but you can use lexers and parsers (`flex` and `bison` being the most common examples).
- No conversion, simply just use the string

---

Since I didn't go into exactly *why* `scanf` is bad in my question, I'll elaborate:

- With the conversion specifiers `%[...]` and `%c`, `scanf` does not eat up whitespace. This is apparently not widely known, as evidenced by the many duplicates of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).
- There is some confusion about when to use the unary `&` operator when referring to `scanf`'s arguments (specifically with strings).
- It's very easy to ignore the return value from `scanf`. This could easily cause undefined behavior from reading an uninitialized variable.
- It's very easy to forget to prevent buffer overflow in `scanf`. `scanf("%s", str)` is just as bad as, if not worse than, `gets`.
- You cannot detect overflow when converting integers with `scanf`. **In fact, overflow causes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer) in these functions.**

---

Comment: "`scanf` does not eat up whitespace." maybe as "`scanf` does not eat up optional leading whitespace.".  Both `%[...]` and `%c` can readily read white-space - although perhaps not as the coder wants..

Answer (score 69):

## TL;DR

`fgets` is for getting the input. `sscanf` is for parsing it afterwards. `scanf` tries to do both at the same time. That's a recipe for trouble. Read first and parse later.

## Why is `scanf` bad?

The main problem is that `scanf` was never intended to deal with user input. It's intended to be used with "perfectly" formatted data. I quoted the word "perfectly" because it's not completely true. But it is not designed to parse data that are as unreliable as user input. By nature, user input is not predictable. Users misunderstands instructions, makes typos, accidentally press enter before they are done etc. One might reasonably ask why a function that should not be used for user input reads from `stdin`. If you are an experienced *nix user the explanation will not come as a surprise but it might confuse Windows users. In *nix systems, it is very common to build programs that work via piping, which means that you send the output of one program to another by piping the `stdout` of the first program to the `stdin` of the second. This way, you can make sure that the output and input are predictable. During these circumstances, `scanf` actually works well. But when working with unpredictable input, you risk all sorts of trouble.

So why aren't there any easy-to-use standard functions for user input? One can only guess here, but I assume that old hardcore C hackers simply thought that the existing functions were good enough, even though they are very clunky. Also, when you look at typical terminal applications they very rarely read user input from `stdin`. Most often you pass all the user input as command line arguments. Sure, there are exceptions, but for most applications, user input is a very minor thing.

## So what can you do?

First of all, `gets` is NOT an alternative. It's dangerous and should NEVER be used. Read here why: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6699433)

My favorite is `fgets` in combination with `sscanf`. I once wrote an answer about that, but I will re-post the complete code. Here is an example with decent (but not perfect) error checking and parsing. It's good enough for debugging purposes.

> #### Note

> I don't particularly like asking the user to input two different things on one single line. I only do that when they belong to each other in a natural way. Like for instance `printf("Enter the price in the format <dollars>.<cent>: "); fgets(buffer, bsize, stdin);` and then use `sscanf(buffer "%d.%d", &dollar, &cent)`. I would never do something like `printf("Enter height and base of the triangle: ")`. The main point of using `fgets` below is to encapsulate the inputs to ensure that one input does not affect the next.

```
#define bsize 100

void error_function(const char *buffer, int no_conversions) {
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred. You entered:\n%s\n", buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d successful conversions", no_conversions);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char c, buffer[bsize];
int x,y;
float f, g;
int r;

printf("Enter two integers: ");
fflush(stdout); // Make sure that the printf is executed before reading
if(! fgets(buffer, bsize, stdin)) error_function(buffer, 0);
if((r = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &x, &y)) != 2) error_function(buffer, r);

// Unless the input buffer was to small we can be sure that stdin is empty
// when we come here.
printf("Enter two floats: ");
fflush(stdout);
if(! fgets(buffer, bsize, stdin)) error_function(buffer, 0);
if((r = sscanf(buffer, "%f%f", &f, &g)) != 2) error_function(buffer, r);

// Reading single characters can be especially tricky if the input buffer
// is not emptied before. But since we're using fgets, we're safe.
printf("Enter a char: ");
fflush(stdout);
if(! fgets(buffer, bsize, stdin)) error_function(buffer, 0);
if((r = sscanf(buffer, "%c", &c)) != 1) error_function(buffer, r);

printf("You entered %d %d %f %c\n", x, y, f, c);
```

> If you do a lot of these, I could recommend creating a wrapper that always flushes:
>
> ```
> int printfflush (const char *format, ...)
> {
>    va_list arg;
>    int done;
>    va_start (arg, format);
>    done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
>    fflush(stdout);
>    va_end (arg);
>    return done;
> }
> ```

Doing like this will eliminate a common problem, which is the trailing newline that can mess with the nest input. But it has another issue, which is if the line is longer than `bsize`. You can check that with `if(buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] != '\n')`. If you want to remove the newline, you can do that with `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0`.

In general, I would advise to not expect the user to enter input in some weird format that you should parse to different variables. If you want to assign the variables `height` and `width`, don't ask for both at the same time. Allow the user to press enter between them. Also, this approach is very natural in one sense. You will never get the input from `stdin` until you hit enter, so why not always read the whole line? Of course this can still lead to issues if the line is longer than the buffer. Did I remember to mention that user input is clunky in C? :)

To avoid problems with lines longer than the buffer you can use a function that automatically allocates a buffer of appropriate size, you can use `getline()`. The drawback is that you will need to `free` the result afterwards. This function is not guaranteed to exist by the standard, but POSIX has it. You could also implement your own, or find one on SO. [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870485/6699433)

## Stepping up the game

If you're serious about creating programs in C with user input, I would recommend having a look at a library like `ncurses`. Because then you likely also want to create applications with some terminal graphics. Unfortunately, you will lose some portability if you do that, but it gives you far better control of user input. For instance, it gives you the ability to read a key press instantly instead of waiting for the user to press enter.

## Interesting reading

Here is a rant about `scanf`: https://web.archive.org/web/20201112034702/http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Note that `(r = sscanf("1 2 junk", "%d%d", &x, &y)) != 2` does not detect as bad the trailing non-numeric text.

Comment: @chux Fixed %f%f. What do you mean with the first?

Comment: With `fgets()` of `"1 2 junk"`, `if((r = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &x, &y)) != 2) {` does not report anything wrong with input even though it has "junk".

Comment: @chux Ah, now I see. Well that was intentional.

Comment: @chux Well intentional was a bit of a stretch. It was more like that I did not care. It was easier to throw away whatever comes behind the numbers than doing extra checking. :)

Comment: The reason there are no good functions for console I/O is that C89 deliberately avoided features that would not be universally supportable, and there is no requirement that C implementations (even hosted ones) have anything that even remotely resembles a console.

Comment: @supercat That sounds very plausible and is a very interesting thing. I might add it to the answer. Do you happen to have a source?

Comment: @klutt: Compilers from Borland and Microsoft both included `getch()` which reads a character from the keyboard without echo, `getche()` which reads and echos a character, `putch()` which outputs a character to the screen, and `cprintf`, which sends a string to the screen; these functions are not affected by I/O redirection.  I think there was also a `cgets()` though I never used it.

Comment: @klutt: Search for "C99 Rationale" for information about why a lot of things in the Standard are as they are (it describes both C89 and C99).  A key thing to understand is that the authors of C89 were chartered with describing an existing language, rather than inventing features, so if different implementations used different ways of doing something, and not all implementations could support it, the Standard would simply ignore the issue on the assumption that because those that could meaningfully support it did so with no standard, they didn't need the Standard to tell them how to do so.

Comment: @klutt: Even just reading the first few parts of the Rationale give an impression of the language which isn't intended to make programmers jump through hoops to accomplish "what needs to be done".

Comment: @supercat Yes, I agree about that. It's just that I prefer to give sources to claims.

Comment: @klutt: The fact that the Standard doesn't require that C implementations support any kind of console could be inferred by the lack of functions for that purpose.  I don't know any particular source for the fact that many pre-standard implementations supported console I/O, other than the documentation for them (which I don't have readily available).  It's too bad the Committee wasn't willing to "invent" some console functions that could be readily supportable on existing implementations with consoles merely by adding them to the library, since no pre-existing functions would be suitable.

Comment: @klutt: On a Unix system, it's necessary to switch the input stream to "raw" mode before characters are typed, making it impractical to support an Borland/MS-style `getch()`, but Unix allows `getchar()` to be used for either buffered or non-buffered input, depending upon the raw-mode setting.  Having a "prepare for getch()" function [which could be a no-op in MS-DOS], combined with `getch()` (which on some platforms would require "preparation") would have allowed programs to support both kinds of console platforms.

Comment: *`scanf` is intended to be used with perfectly formatted data* But even that's not true.  Besides the issue with "junk" as mentioned by @chux, there's also the fact that a format like `"%d %d %d"` is happy to read input from one, two, or three lines (or even more, if there are intervening blank lines), that there's no way to force (say) a two-line input by doing something like `"%d\n%d %d"`, etc.  `scanf` might be appropriate for formatted *stream* input, but it's not at all good for anything line-based.

Comment: @SteveSummit: In general, "perfectly" formatted data will have known numbers of items per line. and `scanf` will be of marginal use when handling data that doesn't have known numbers of items per line.  What part of the statement are you disagreeing with?

Comment: @supercat This comment box isn't big enough for a full answer, but it's kind of like the old joke, "If we had some ham, we could make a ham sandwich... if we had some bread."  Your statement about `scanf` was partly true, but it didn't go far enough.  I'd say: "`scanf` is lousy for user input, because user input is unformatted, and `scanf` is designed for formatted input... but `scanf` is lousy for formatted input." (Because, among other things, it can be both too forgiving, and not forgiving enough.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: In those cases where the format of the input is so strongly guaranteed that the programmer would genuinely not need to care about how code would process anything else, `scanf` would be usable.  Having standard library include a function that's about half the size *of an entire Pascal compiler with built-in IDE* just for the purpose of handling such rare cases seems a bit silly, but that doesn't mean the function is *completely* useless.

Comment: @chqrlie Nice. Updated

Answer (score 22):

`scanf` is awesome when you *know* your input is always well-structured and well-behaved. Otherwise...

IMO, here are the biggest problems with `scanf`:

- **Risk of buffer overflow** - if you do not specify a field width for the `%s` and `%[` conversion specifiers, you risk a buffer overflow (trying to read more input than a buffer is sized to hold).  Unfortunately, there's no good way to specify that as an argument (as with `printf`) - you have to either hardcode it as part of the conversion specifier or do some macro shenanigans.
- **Accepts inputs that *should* be rejected** - If you're reading an input with the `%d` conversion specifier and you type something like `12w4`, you would *expect* `scanf` to reject that input, but it doesn't - it successfully converts and assigns the `12`, leaving `w4` in the input stream to foul up the next read.

So, what should you use instead?

I usually recommend reading *all* interactive input as text using `fgets` - it allows you to specify a maximum number of characters to read at a time, so you can easily prevent buffer overflow:

```
char input[100];
if ( !fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) )
{
  // error reading from input stream, handle as appropriate
}
else
{
  // process input buffer
}
```

One quirk of `fgets` is that it will store the trailing newline in the buffer if there's room, so you can do an easy check to see if someone typed in more input than you were expecting:

```
char *newline = strchr( input, '\n' );
if ( !newline )
{
  // input longer than we expected
}
```

How you deal with that is up to you - you can either reject the whole input out of hand, and slurp up any remaining input with `getchar`:

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' ) 
  ; // empty loop
```

Or you can process the input you got so far and read again.  It depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

To *tokenize* the input (split it up based on one or more delimiters), you can use `strtok`, but beware - `strtok` modifies its input (it overwrites delimiters with the string terminator), and you can't preserve its state (i.e., you can't partially tokenize one string, then start to tokenize another, then pick up where you left off in the original string).  There's a variant, `strtok_s`, that preserves the state of the tokenizer, but AFAIK its implementation is optional (you'll need to check that `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined to see if it's available).

Once you've tokenized your input, if you need to convert strings to numbers (i.e., `"1234"` => `1234`), you have options.  `strtol` and `strtod` will convert string representations of integers and real numbers to their respective types.  They also allow you to catch the `12w4` issue I mentioned above - one of their arguments is a pointer to the first character *not* converted in the string:

```
char *text = "12w4";
char *chk;
long val;
long tmp = strtol( text, &chk, 10 );
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  // input is not a valid integer string, reject the entire input
else
  val = tmp;
```

Comment: *If you do not specify a field width*... - or a conversion suppression (e.g. `%*[%\n]`, which is useful for dealing with overlong lines later in the answer).

Comment: There is a way to get run-time specification of field widths, but it's not nice.  You end up having to construct the format string in your code (perhaps using `snprintf()`), .

Comment: You've made the most common mistake with `isspace()` there - it accepts *unsigned* characters represented as `int`, so you need to cast to `unsigned char` to avoid UB on platforms where `char` is signed.

Answer (score 11):

In this answer I'm going to assume that you are reading and
interpreting *lines of text*.
Perhaps you're prompting the user, who is typing something and
hitting RETURN.  Or perhaps you're reading lines of structured
text from a data file of some kind.

Since you're reading lines of text, it makes sense to organize
your code around a library function that reads, well, a line of
text.
The Standard function is `fgets()`, although there are others (including [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)).  And then the next step is to interpret
that line of text somehow.

Here's the basic recipe for calling `fgets` to read a line of
text:

```
char line[512];
printf("type something:\n");
fgets(line, 512, stdin);
printf("you typed: %s", line);
```

This simply reads in one line of text and prints it back out.
As written it has a couple of limitations, which we'll get to in
a minute.  It also has a very great feature: that number 512 we
passed as the second argument to `fgets` is the size of the array
`line` we're asking `fgets` to read into.  This fact -- that we can
tell `fgets` how much it's allowed to read -- means that we can
be sure that `fgets` won't overflow the array by reading too much
into it.

So now we know how to read a line of text, but what if we really
wanted to read an integer, or a floating-point number, or a
single character, or a single word?  (That is, what if the
`scanf` call we're trying to improve on had been using a format
specifier like `%d`, `%f`, `%c`, or `%s`?)

It's easy to reinterpret a line of text -- a string -- as any of these things.
To convert a string to an integer, the simplest (though
imperfect) way to do it is to call `atoi()`.
To convert to a floating-point number, there's `atof()`.
(And there are also better ways, as we'll see in a minute.)
Here's a very simple example:

```
printf("type an integer:\n");
fgets(line, 512, stdin);
int i = atoi(line);
printf("type a floating-point number:\n");
fgets(line, 512, stdin);
float f = atof(line);
printf("you typed %d and %f\n", i, f);
```

If you wanted the user to type a single character (perhaps `y` or
`n` as a yes/no response), you can literally just grab the first
character of the line, like this:

```
printf("type a character:\n");
fgets(line, 512, stdin);
char c = line[0];
printf("you typed %c\n", c);
```

(This ignores, of course, the possibility that the user typed a
multi-character response; it quietly ignores any extra characters
that were typed.)

Finally, if you wanted the user to type a string definitely *not* containing
whitespace, if you wanted to treat the input line

```
hello world!
```

as the string `"hello"` followed by something else (which is what
the `scanf` format `%s` would have done), well, in that case, I
fibbed a little, it's not quite so easy to reinterpret the line
in that way, after all, so the answer to that part of the question will have
to wait for a bit.

But first I want to go back to three things I skipped over.

(1) We've been calling

```
fgets(line, 512, stdin);
```

to read into the array `line`, and where 512 is the size of the
array `line` so `fgets` knows not to overflow it.  But to make
sure that 512 is the right number (especially, to check if maybe
someone tweaked the program to change the size), you have to read
back to wherever `line` was declared.  That's a nuisance, so
there are two much better ways to keep the sizes in sync.
You could, (a) use the preprocessor to make a name for the size:

```
#define MAXLINE 512
char line[MAXLINE];
fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin);
```

Or, (b) use C's `sizeof` operator:

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
```

(2) The second problem is that we haven't been checking for
error.  When you're reading input, you should *always* check for
the possibility of error.  If for whatever reason `fgets` can't
read the line of text you asked it to, it indicates this by
returning a null pointer.  So we should have been doing things like

```
printf("type something:\n");
if(fgets(line, 512, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("Well, never mind, then.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Finally, there's the issue that in order to read a line of text,
`fgets` reads characters and fills them into your array until it
finds the `\n` character that terminates the line, *and it fills
the `\n` character into your array, too*.  You can see this if
you modify our earlier example slightly:

```
printf("you typed: \"%s\"\n", line);
```

If I run this and type "Steve" when it prompts me, it prints out

```
you typed: "Steve
"
```

That `"` on the second line is because the string it read and
printed back out was actually `"Steve\n"`.

Sometimes that extra newline doesn't matter (like when we called
`atoi` or `atof`, since they both ignore any extra non-numeric
input after the number), but sometimes it matters a lot.  So
often we'll want to strip that newline off.  There are several
ways to do that, which I'll get to in a minute.  (I know I've been
saying that a lot.  But I will get back to all those things, I promise.)

At this point, you may be thinking: "I thought you said `scanf`
was no good, and this other way would be so much better.
But `fgets` is starting to look like a nuisance.
Calling `scanf` was *so easy*!  Can't I keep using it?"

Sure, you can keep using `scanf`, if you want.  (And for *really*
simple things, in some ways it is simpler.)  But, please, don't
come crying to me when it fails you due to one of its 17 quirks
and foibles, or goes into an infinite loop because of input your
didn't expect, or when you can't figure out how to use it to do
something more complicated.  And let's take a look at `fgets`'s
actual nuisances:

1. You always have to specify the array size.  Well, of course,
   that's not a nuisance at all -- that's a feature, because buffer
   overflow is a Really Bad Thing.
2. You have to check the return value.  Actually, that's a wash,
   because to use `scanf` correctly, you have to check its return
   value, too.
3. You have to strip the `\n` back off.  This is, I admit, a true
   nuisance.  I wish there were a Standard function I could point
   you to that didn't have this little problem.  (Please nobody
   bring up `gets`.)  But compared to `scanf's` 17 different
   nuisances, I'll take this one nuisance of `fgets` any day.

So how *do* you strip that newline?  There are many ways:

(a) Obvious way:

```
char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
if(p != NULL) *p = '\0';
```

(b) Tricky & compact way:

```
strtok(line, "\n");
```

Unfortunately this [doesn't work quite right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893145) on empty lines.

(c) Another compact and mildly obscure way:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

And there are other ways as well.  Me, I always just use (a), since it's simple & obvious, if less than concise.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893145/why-should-strtokline-n-not-be-used-to-strip-the-newline-left-by-fgets), for more (much more) on stripping the `\n` from what `fgets` gives you.

And now that that's out of the way, we can get back to another
thing I skipped over: the imperfections of `atoi()` and `atof()`.
The problem with those is they don't give you any useful
indication of success or failure: they quietly ignore
trailing nonnumeric input, and they quietly return 0 if there's
no numeric input at all.  The preferred alternatives -- which
also have certain other advantages -- are `strtol` and `strtod`.
`strtol` also lets you use a base other than 10, meaning you can
get the effect of (among other things) `%o` or `%x` with `scanf`.
But showing how to use these functions correctly is a story in itself,
and would be too much of a distraction from what is already turning
into a pretty fragmented narrative, so I'm not going to say
anything more about them now.

The rest of the main narrative concerns input you might be trying
to parse that's more complicated than just a single number or
character.  What if you want to read a line containing two
numbers, or multiple whitespace-separated words, or specific
framing punctuation?  That's where things get interesting, and
where things were probably getting complicated if you were trying
to do things using `scanf`, and where there are vastly more
options now that you've cleanly read one line of text using `fgets`,
although the full story on all those options could probably fill
a book, so we're only going to be able to scratch the surface here.

1. My favorite technique is to break the line up into
   whitespace-separated "words", then do something further with each
   "word".  One principal Standard function for doing this is
   `strtok` (which also has its issues, and which also rates a whole
   separate discussion).  My own preference is a dedicated function
   for constructing an array of pointers to each broken-apart
   "word", a function I describe in
   [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html).
   At any rate, once you've got "words", you can further process
   each one, perhaps with the same `atoi`/`atof`/`strtol`/`strtod`
   functions we've already looked at.
2. Paradoxically, even though we've been spending a fair amount of
   time and effort here figuring out how to move away from `scanf`,
   another fine way to deal with the line of text we just read with
   `fgets` is to pass it to `sscanf`.  In this way, you end up with
   most of the advantages of `scanf`, but without most of the
   disadvantages.
3. If your input syntax is particularly complicated, it might be appropriate to use a "regexp" library to parse it.
4. Finally, you can use whatever *ad hoc* parsing solutions suit
   you.  You can move through the line a character at a time with a
   `char *` pointer checking for characters you expect.  Or you can
   search for specific characters using functions like `strchr` or `strrchr`,
   or `strspn` or `strcspn`, or `strpbrk`.  Or you can parse/convert
   and skip over groups of digit characters using the `strtol` or
   `strtod` functions that we skipped over earlier.

There's obviously much more that could be said, but hopefully
this introduction will get you started.

Comment: Is there a good reason to write `sizeof (line)` rather than simply `sizeof line`?  The former makes it look like `line` is a type name!

Comment: @TobySpeight A good reason? No, I doubt it.  The parentheses are my habit, because I can't be bothered to remember whether it's objects or type names they're required for, but many programmers leave them out when they can.  (To me it's a matter of personal preference and style, and a pretty minor one at that.)

Comment: +1 for using `sscanf` as a conversion engine but collecting (and possibly massaging) the input with a different tool. But maybe worth mentioning `getline` in taht context.

Comment: When you talk about "`fscanf`'s actual nuisances", do you mean `fgets`?  And nuisance #3 really irks me, especially given that `scanf` returns a useless pointer to the buffer rather than returning the number of characters input (which would make stripping off the newline much cleaner).

Comment: Thanks for explanation of your `sizeof` style.  For me, remembering when you nee the parens is easy: I think of `(type)` as being like a cast without a value (because we're only interested in the type).  One other thing: you say that `strtok(line, "\n")` doesn't always work, but it's not obvious when it might not.  I'm guessing you're thinking of the case where the line was longer than the buffer, so we have no newline, and `strtok()` returns null?  It's a real pity `fgets()` doesn't return a more useful value so we can know whether the newline is there or not.

Comment: I suppose one way to know whether the full line was read is to put a sentinel NUL at the end of the buffer, (at `line[(sizeof line) - 2]`).  If that's not a newline or NUL after reading, then we've read a partial line.

Comment: @supercat I certainly did.  Fixed.  Thanks.  And #3 really annoys me, too.  (But when you talk about "especially given that `scanf` returns", do you mean ... ? :-) )

Comment: @TobySpeight I think I've seen the `line[(sizeof line)-2]` trick suggested before.  (It'd be "a more efficient way to know whether the full line was read", of course, as we already have one way, albeit a less than perfectly efficient/convenient one.)

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't mention the `strtok` failure case because I don't remember it!  But there's another regular here on [c] -- perhaps chux -- who has mentioned it.  (Returning null isn't a problem, as we're ignoring the return value.)

Comment: @dmckee Meant to mention `getline`; thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @TobySpeight: `strtok(line, "\n");` does not work if the line has just a single `'\n'` in it. This is a major problem! Furthermore `strtok()` has a side effect on a global hidden variable... Don't use this *tricky and bogus* way, and stay away from `strtok()` altogether.

Comment: @chqrlie Thank you very much for clarifying that, even over a year later, and I'm sorry if I misremembered chux as you. :-)

Answer (score 10):

> What can I use to parse input instead of scanf?

Instead of `scanf(some_format, ...)`, consider `fgets()` with `sscanf(buffer, some_format_and %n, ...)`

By using `" %n"`, code can simply detect if *all* the format was successfully scanned and that no extra non-white-space junk was at the end.

```
// scanf("%d %f fred", &some_int, &some_float);
#define EXPECTED_LINE_MAX 100
char buffer[EXPECTED_LINE_MAX * 2];  // Suggest 2x, no real need to be stingy.

if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  int n = 0;
  // add ----------------> " %n" -----------------------, &n
  sscanf(buffer, "%d %f fred %n", &some_int, &some_float, &n);
  // Did scan complete, and to the end?
  if (n > 0 && buffer[n] == '\0') {
    // success, use `some_int, some_float`
  } else {
    ; // Report bad input and handle desired.
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's state the requirements of parsing as:

- valid input must be accepted (and converted into some other form)
- invalid input must be rejected
- **when any input is rejected, it is necessary to provide the user with a descriptive message that explains (in clear "easily understood by normal people who are not programmers" language) why it was rejected (so that people can figure out how to fix the problem)**

To keep things very simple, lets consider parsing a single simple decimal integer (that was typed in by the user) and nothing else. Possible reasons for the user's input to be rejected are:

- the input contained unacceptable characters
- the input represents a number that is lower than the accepted minimum
- the input represents a number that is higher than the accepted maximum
- the input represents a number that has a non-zero fractional part

Let's also define "input contained unacceptable characters" properly; and say that:

- leading whitespace and trailing whitespace will be ignored (e.g. "
  5    " will be treated as "5")
- zero or one decimal point is allowed (e.g. "1234." and "1234.000" are both treated the same as "1234")
- there must be at least one digit (e.g. "." is rejected)
- no more than one decimal point is allowed (e.g. "1.2.3" is rejected)
- commas that are not between digits will be rejected (e.g. ",1234" is rejected)
- commas that are after a decimal point will be rejected (e.g. "1234.000,000" is rejected)
- commas that are after another comma are rejected (e.g. "1,,234" is rejected)
- all other commas will be ignored (e.g. "1,234" will be treated as "1234")
- a minus sign that is not the first non-whitespace character is rejected
- a positive sign that is not the first non-whitespace character is rejected

From this we can determine that the following error messages are needed:

- "Unknown character at start of input"
- "Unknown character at end of input"
- "Unknown character in middle of input"
- "Number is too low (minimum is ....)"
- "Number is too high (maximum is ....)"
- "Number is not an integer"
- "Too many decimal points"
- "No decimal digits"
- "Bad comma at start of number"
- "Bad comma at end of number"
- "Bad comma in middle of number"
- "Bad comma after decimal point"

From this point we can see that a suitable function to convert a string into an integer would need to distinguish between very different types of errors; and that something like "`scanf()`" or "`atoi()`" or "`strtoll()`" is completely and utterly worthless because they fail to give you any indication of what was wrong with the input (and use a completely irrelevant and inappropriate definition of what is/isn't "valid input").

Instead, lets start writing something that isn't useless:

```
char *convertStringToInteger(int *outValue, char *string, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    return "Code not implemented yet!";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *errorString;
    int value;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("ERROR: No command line argument.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    errorString = convertStringToInteger(&value, argv[1], -10, 2000);
    if(errorString != NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", errorString);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("SUCCESS: Your number is %d\n", value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**To meet the stated requirements; this `convertStringToInteger()` function is likely to end up being several hundred lines of code all by itself.**

Now, this was just "parsing a single simple decimal integer". Imagine if you wanted to parse something complex; like a list of "name, street address, phone number, email address" structures; or maybe like a programming language. For these cases you might need to write thousands of lines of code to create a parse that isn't a crippled joke.

In other words...

> What can I use to parse input instead of scanf?

Write (potentially thousands of lines) of code yourself, to suit your requirements.

Comment: This is the only way. Do NOT use the libc for vast majority of things.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of using `flex` to scan a simple input, in this case a file of ASCII floating point numbers that might be in either US (`n,nnn.dd`) or European (`n.nnn,dd`) formats. This is just copied from a much larger program, so there may be some unresolved references:

```
/* This scanner reads a file of numbers, expecting one number per line.  It  */
/* allows for the use of European-style comma as decimal point.              */

%{
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <io.h>
  #endif
  #include "Point.h"

  #define YY_NO_UNPUT
  #define YY_DECL int f_lex (double *val)

  double atofEuro (char *);
%}

%option prefix="f_"
%option nounput
%option noinput

EURONUM [-+]?[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
NUMBER  [-+]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
WS      [ \t\x0d]

%%

[!@#%&*/].*\n

^{WS}*{EURONUM}{WS}*  { *val = atofEuro (yytext); return (1); }
^{WS}*{NUMBER}{WS}*   { *val = atof (yytext); return (1); }

[\n]
.


%%

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int scan_f (FILE *in, double *vals, int max)
{
  double *val;
  int npts, rc;

  f_in = in;
  val  = vals;
  npts = 0;
  while (npts < max)
  {
    rc = f_lex (val);

    if (rc == 0)
      break;
    npts++;
    val++;
  }

  return (npts);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int f_wrap ()
{
  return (1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common uses of `scanf` is to read a single `int` as input from the user. Therefore, I will write an answer which focusses on this one problem only.

Here is an example of how `scanf` is commonly used for reading an `int` from the user:

```
int num;

printf( "Please enter an integer: " );

if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1 )
{
    printf( "Error converting input!\n" );
}
else
{
    printf( "The input was successfully converted to %d.\n", num );
}
```

Using `scanf` in this manner has several problems:

The function `scanf` will not always read a whole line of input.

If the input conversion fails due to the user entering bad input such as `abc`, then the bad input will be left on the input stream. If this bad input is not discarded afterwards, then all further calls to `scanf` with the `%d` format specifier will immediately fail, without waiting for the user to enter further input. This may cause an infinite loop.

Even if the input conversion succeeds, any trailing bad input will be left on the input stream. For example, if the user enters `6abc`, then `scanf` will successfully convert the `6`, but leave `abc` on the input stream. If this input is not discarded, then we will once again have the problem of all further calls to `scanf` with the `%d` format specifier immediately failing, which may cause an infinite loop.

Even in the case of the input succeeding and the user not entering any trailing bad input, the mere fact that `scanf` generally leaves the newline character on the input stream can cause trouble, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/12149471).

Another issue with using `scanf` with the `%d` format spcifier is that if the result of the conversion is not representable as an `int` (e.g. if the result is larger than [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)), then, according to [§7.21.6.2 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10), the behavior of the program is undefined, which means that you cannot rely on any specific behavior.

In order to solve all of the issues mentioned above, it is generally better to use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), which will always read an entire line of input at once, if possible. This function will read the input as a string. After doing this, you can use the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to attempt to convert the string to an integer. Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[200], *p;
    int num;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Enter a number: " );

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Input failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to convert string to integer
    num = strtol( line, &p, 10 );
    if ( p == line )
    {
        printf( "Unable to convert to integer!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print result
    printf( "Conversion successful! The number is %d.\n", num );
}
```

However, this code has the following issues:

1. It does not check whether the input line was too long to fit into the buffer.
2. It does not check whether the converted number is representable as an `int`, for example whether the number is too large to be stored in an `int`.
3. It will accept `6abc` as valid input for the number `6`. This is not as bad as `scanf`, because `scanf` will leave `abc` on the input stream, whereas `fgets` will not. However, it would probably still be better to reject the input instead of accepting it.

All of these issues can be solved by doing the following:

Issue #1 can be solved by checking

- whether the input buffer contains a newline character, or
- whether end-of-file has been reached, which can be treated as equivalent to a newline character, because it also indicates the end of the line.

Issue #2 can be solved by checking whether the function `strtol` set `errno` to the value of the macro constant `ERANGE`, to determine whether the converted value is representable as a `long`. In order to determine whether this value is also representable as an `int`, the value returned by `strtol` should be compared against [`INT_MIN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) and `INT_MAX`.

Issue #3 can be solved by checking all remaining characters on the line. Since `strtol` accepts leading [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), it would probably also be appropriate to accept trailing whitespace characters. However, if the input contains any other trailing characters, the input should probably be rejected.

Here is an improved version of the code, which solves all of the issues mentioned above and also puts everything into a function named `get_int_from_user`. This function will automatically reprompt the user for input, until the input is valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6abc" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int number;

    number = get_int_from_user( "Enter a number: " );

    printf( "Input was valid.\n" );
    printf( "The number is: %d\n", number );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter a number: abc
Error converting string to number!
Enter a number: 6000000000
Number out of range error!
Enter a number: 6 7 8
Unexpected input encountered!
Enter a number: 6abc
Unexpected input encountered!
Enter a number: 6
Input was valid.
The number is: 6
```

Answer (score -6):

Other answers give the right low-level details, so I'll limit myself to a higher-level: First, analyse *what you expect* each input line to look like.  Try to describe the input with a formal syntax - with luck, you will find it can be described using a *regular grammar*, or at least a *context-free grammar*.  If a regular grammar suffices, then you can code up a *finite-state machine* which recognizes and interprets each command-line one character at a time.  Your code will then read a line (as explained in other replies), then scan the chars in the buffer through the state-machine.  At certain states you stop and convert the substring scanned thus far to a number or whatever.  You can probably 'roll your own' if it is this simple; if you find you require a full context-free grammar you are better off figuring out how to use existing parsing tools (re: `lex` and `yacc` or their variants).

Comment: A finite state machine may be overkill; easier ways to detect overflow in conversions (such as checking if `errno == EOVERFLOW` after using `strtoll`) are possible.

Comment: Why would you code your own finite state machine, when flex makes writing them trivially simple?