# Typing Ctrl+Z twice vs just once

Tags: c, scanf, eof

I'm using Windows and CodeBlocks IDE by the way.

If my code was( has space before the `%d` specifier):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number you want to check is present: ");

       while(scanf(" %d",&num)==EOF) // As long as wrong input is present on buffer
       {
          printf("Please enter valid input...\n");
          //clear the input buffer
       }
    return 0;
}
```

I've have to type in `Ctrl+Z` twice(once on each line,doesn't have to be at the beginning of line) for the  `while(scanf(" %d",&num)==EOF)` case to run.

Whereas if my code was:
If my code was(no space before the `%d` specifier):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number you want to check is present: ");

       while(scanf("%d",&num)==EOF) // As long as wrong input is present on buffer
       {
          printf("Please enter valid input...\n");
          //clear the input buffer
       }
    return 0;
}
```

I've have to type in `Ctrl+Z` once for the `while(scanf("%d",&num)==EOF)` case to run.

So there are 2 parts in this question:

1)Why do I need to press `Ctrl+Z` twice for the first example? I tried to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261742/10701114 but it was for UNIX and kind of confusing for me

2) Why does the space before the `%d` specifier even cause such a discrepancy since it shouldn't matter unless its a `%n`,`%c` or `%[...]` (I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504282/10701114)?

NOTE: If I should post these 2 parts as 2 questions, please do comment.

**Update** : I tried this on the cmd prompt with gcc(my first  time on a cmd prompt), the same issue persists

Comment: In the Windows console (the "DOS prompt") you must press `Ctrl-Z` on an empty line for it to be detected as `EOF`.

Comment: On CodeBlocks,even if its an empty line, I still have to press `Ctrl-Z` twice. ( I pressed `Enter` to go to a newline and pressed `Ctrl-Z` once, it didn't work till I pressed another `Ctrl-Z` ) . Does it only work properly on the Windows console?

Comment: It's possible that the console in your IDE doesn't follow the same rules as the Windows console. You should try running it outside of the IDE in a normal Windows console and verify its behavior there.

Comment: Should the 2nd "I've have to type in Ctrl+Z once for the `while(scanf(" %d",&num)==EOF)` case to run." --> "I've have to type in Ctrl+Z once for the `while(scanf("%d",&num)==EOF)` case to run."?  (no space)

Comment: And the UNIX stuff won't apply to anything on Windows. Windows doesn't even know what a TTY is, and its EOF behavior is as stated by @Someprogrammerdude, which is different from behavior in UNIX TTYs (virtual or otherwise).

Comment: The it could be a buffering issue of Code:Blocks itself and how it handles input.

Comment: Leon, Please clarify that there is no prior I/O function and you provided no prior input.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What I pasted is actually the entire program

Comment: Loen, "actually the entire program" --> no `main()`?

Comment: As in I didn't paste everything

Comment: @MemReflect I currently don't have a compiler that doesn't rely on an IDE. I will get back asap once I try it on the windows console

Comment: `int num, rtn; ... while (1) { rtn = scanf ("%d", &num); if (rtn == EOF) { /* handle EOF */} else if (rtn == 1) { /* good input, validate range, clear remaining, break */ } else { /* invalid input - matching failure */ }}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the problem still persists with your code

Comment: @Leon You understand why? When you have, e.g. `"abcd"` and press [Ctrl+z], you signify end-of-input for`"abcd"` and that is taken as your input, `EOF` is not returned. `scanf()` then blocks again waiting for input. On the second press of [Ctrl+z], there is no input and an *input failure* occurs and `scanf()` then returns `EOF` breaking the loop. The code I posted was to show to handle all 3 possible conditions you must validate to use `scanf()` correctly.